# How can we reach global optimum?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

Gradient descent can get stuck into local optimum. Which techniques are there to reach global optimum?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid falling into the "local minima" trap?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/how-to-avoid-falling-into-the-local-minima-trap)

Answer (score 1):

In Deep Learning there are several methods to improve "stuck" gradient - decrease learning rate, use cyclic learning rate - cycle it from bigger to smaller value. More radical method is completely reinitialize last or two last (before loss) layers of the network.

In non-Deep Learning ML out of those only decrease learning rate will work, but there is plethora Numerical Optimization methods to help, like second-order methods - variation of Gauss-Newton, or methods specific to the problem which may include projective methods, alternate directions, conjugate gradients [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Optimization_algorithms). There are a lot of methods which are better then gradient descent for non-Deep Learning optimization.